# Selenium C# to select UL IL and Label value

Tags: c#, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am a beginner to use the Selenium in C#. I am trying to get the value from UL list. Here is the HTML code.

```
     <div class="reg-field__popup">
   <div class="form__popup-error form__popup-text" data-t="login-error" role="alert">
      <div class="form__login-suggest">
         <strong class="suggest__status-text error-message">You must select a&nbsp;username</strong>
         <div>
            <div class="suggest__logins">
               <strong class="suggest__status-text" tabindex="4">Available usernames</strong>
               <ul class="logins__list">
                  <li class="registration__pseudo-link">
                     <label for="lill1an.amir" tabindex="0" title="lill1an.amir" data-login="lill1an.amir">
                        <input type="radio" id="lill1an.amir" value="on"><!-- react-text: 1218 -->lill1an.amir<!-- /react-text -->
                     </label>
                  </li>
                  <li class="registration__pseudo-link">
                     <label for="lilli4n.a" tabindex="0" title="lilli4n.a" data-login="lilli4n.a">
                        <input type="radio" id="lilli4n.a" value="on"><!-- react-text: 1222 -->lilli4n.a<!-- /react-text -->
                     </label>
                  </li>
```

I need to get the value of the label. The result will be `lill1an.amir`, `lilli4n.a`

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Then read [ask] and take a few minutes to add some details to your question, especially an [mcve].

Comment: @bugfreerammohan During your question edit you have **massacred** the query while editing the desired output. I am restoring it back for the time being but moving forward please take care. Else OP won't be able to receive canonical answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var labels = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'logins__list')/li]"))

for (int a = 0; a < labels.Count; a++) {
    Console.WriteLine(labels[a].FindElement(By.Xpath("./label")).GetAttribute("for"))
}
```

EDIT:

also, this should work (thanks Moshe Slavin):

```
for (int a = 0; a < labels.Count; a++) {
    Console.WriteLine(labels[a].FindElement(By.Xpath("./label/input")).GetAttribute("value")) # or GetAttribute("innerHTML")
}
```

Comment: Oh, right, but in that case the xpath would be "./label/input", either will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var ulList = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath('//ul[@class="logins__list"]'))
```

Then use `GetAttribute("value")` in a for loop...

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML to extract the desired texts i.e. **lill1an.amir**, **lilli4n.a** from the `<label>` you can use the following solution:

```
labels = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@class='logins__list']//li/label"))
foreach (IWebElement label in labels)
{
    string my_text = field.GetAttribute("for");
    Console.WriteLine(my_text);
}
```